# fmt.Print not working as intended after reading input from the terminal

Tags: go

I am trying out a basic print program which takes Weight and Height as inputs and prints them back in the same line without any space or line breaks.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

var reader = bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("BMI Calculator")
    fmt.Print("Please enter your weight (Kg): ")
    weightInput, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Print("Please enter your height (m): ")
    heightInput, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    weightInput = strings.Replace(weightInput, "\n", "", -1)
    heightInput = strings.Replace(heightInput, "\n", "", -1)

    fmt.Print(weightInput)
    fmt.Print(heightInput)
}
```

For example when I enter weight as 70 and height as 1.8, it should ideally print **701.8**
But I am not getting any output after taking the height input, the program is completing execution without printing the weightInput and heightInput (Program output below:)

```
BMI Calculator
Please enter your weight (Kg): 70
Please enter your height (m): 1.8
```

However when I change the last two lines to:

```
fmt.Println(weightInput)
fmt.Println(heightInput)
```

I get the correct output 70 and 1.8 in two different lines as follows:

```
Please enter your weight (Kg): 70
Please enter your height (m): 1.8
70 
1.8
```

Why is this not working as intended with the `fmt.Print` function?

I tried removing the lines where I am taking inputs from the user, and replaced it with hard-coded strings as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("BMI Calculator")
    weightInput := "70"
    heightInput := "1.8"

    weightInput = strings.Replace(weightInput, "\n", "", -1)
    heightInput = strings.Replace(heightInput, "\n", "", -1)

    fmt.Print(weightInput)
    fmt.Print(heightInput)
}
```

In this case I get the desired output:

```
BMI Calculator
701.8
```

Why is the `fmt.Print` acting differently in case of taking inputs from the user and in cases of hard-coded strings, and how to correctly use `fmt.Print` when taking input from the user?

Comment: Yeah that is why I am using the **strings.Replace** function to replace the delim in the next line.

Also this does not explain why the **fmt.Print** function is not able to print the correct output, but **fmt.Println** is able to print the correct output

Comment: What shell are you using? Many are going to handle output line buffered, so without a trailing newline it won't display immediately and you may not see anything if it's consumed into the next prompt.

Comment: Your OS is Windows: EOL is CRLF. Use striings.TrimSpace, not strings.Replace.

Comment: @rocka2q yes, that's probably a better guess

Comment: @rocka2q how does that explain the fact that the `fmt.Print` version doesn't produce _any_ output? Are you saying that `strings.Replace(s, "\n", "", -1)` _deletes_ the whole input because CRLF?

Comment: @mkopriva: `\r` returns to the start of the same line, so the after each output the curser overwrites what you just wrote

Comment: After replacing `strings.Replace` with `strings.TrimSpace` everything works correctly. But can anyone explain why there was no issue with `fmt.Println` earlier?  Thank you @JimB, @rocka2q and @mkopriva

Answer (score -2):

The behavior you're observing is due to the way terminal input buffering works. When you read input from the user using bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin).ReadString('\n'), it reads the input up to and including the newline character ('\n'). When you press Enter after entering the height, it not only captures the height but also the newline character, which is included in the heightInput variable.

So, when you later use fmt.Print(heightInput), it's actually printing the newline character, and that's why you don't see any visible output. In contrast, when you hard-code the strings, you don't have this newline character, which is why you get the expected output.

To achieve the desired output, you can trim the newline characters from the input strings using the strings.TrimRight function. Here's how you can modify your code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

var reader = bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("BMI Calculator")
    fmt.Print("Please enter your weight (Kg): ")
    weightInput, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Print("Please enter your height (m): ")
    heightInput, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    weightInput = strings.TrimRight(weightInput, "\n")
    heightInput = strings.TrimRight(heightInput, "\n")

    fmt.Print(weightInput)
    fmt.Print(heightInput)
}
```

With this modification, your program will work as expected, whether you enter the values manually or hard-code them. It trims the newline character ('\n') from the end of the input strings, ensuring that the output is printed without any unwanted line breaks.

Comment: This is why I have removed the '\n' character by using `strings.Replace` function in the code snippet provided. I am still confused why `fmt.Println` is printing the correct desired output but `fmt.Print` is not printing anything.